# How to handle clicked item in v-if

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I have one colorpicker for each cell, but when i click the colorpicker show event it opens everyone in the table instead of the clicked one. How can i do this? Any advice?

```
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Escuela</th>
          <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody v-for="institution in institutions">
       <tr>
         <td>
          <p>{{ institution.name }}</p>  
         </td>
         <td>
          <div class="task">
          <span class="current-color" :style="'background-color: ' + institution.color" @click="toggleItem()"></span>
            <sketch-picker v-model="institution.color" v-show="toggled" />
          </div>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

And

```
<script>
  import { Sketch } from 'vue-color'
  import { Chrome } from 'vue-color'
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        institutions:[
          {
            name: "UANL",
            color: "#6b5b95"
          },
          {
            name: "CONALEP",
            color: "#feb236"
          },
          {
            name: "ESCUELA",
            color: "#d64161"
          }
        ],
        toggled: false,
      }
    }, 
    components: {
      'chrome-picker': Chrome,
      'sketch-picker': Sketch,
    },
    methods: {
      toggleItems(){
        this.toggled = !this.toggled;
      },
      toggleItem: function() {
      this.toggled = !this.toggled;
    }
    }
  }
  //export default {}

</script>
```

But when i click one span, every color picker shows up instead of showing only the clicked one. How can I fix this? I just can't find a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you toggle the item, send it through to your function:

```
  <span class="current-color" :style="'background-color: ' + institution.color" @click="toggleItem(institution)"></span>
```

and then make that the value of your `toggled` property:

```
  toggleItem: function(item) {
    this.toggled = this.toggled != item ? item : null;
  }
```

and finally your show condition should check if the current loop item equals the one which is currently toggled:

```
<sketch-picker v-model="institution.color" v-show="toggled == institution" />
```

Comment: Is there any way to when clicked again it closes?

Answer (score 0):

As you are toggling `toggled` which is directly modeled for all the elements in your loop. And when `toggled = true`, you see the element displayed for all the `instructions` in `v-for` loop. coz this is the condition you've set to show the elements and not for any individual element

What I would suggest you to is change your `institutions` array structure a little bit to

```
institutions:[
      {
        name: "UANL",
        color: "#6b5b95",
        toggled: false
      },
      {
        name: "CONALEP",
        color: "#feb236",
        toggled: false
      },
      {
        name: "ESCUELA",
        color: "#d64161",
        toggled: false
      }
    ],
```

And change you `html` to

```
 <span class="current-color" :style="'background-color: ' + institution.color" @click="toggleItem(institution)"></span>

 <sketch-picker v-model="institution.color" v-show="institution.toggled" />
```

And now your method should look like

```
toggleItems(institution){
    institution.toggled = !institution.toggled;
  },
```

Comment: It is a good idea but the institutions array will be coming from a server.
Any workaround?

Comment: won't matter. In that case you'll just have to change `institution.toggled` to `institution['toggled'] ` in your method

Comment: at first they will be undefined and will be treated as false and when you click, this will set `toggled` property on it